# Error "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b windows 10 64 bit" fix

Tags: windows-10

As the name suggests, I'm getting this error "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b windows 10 64 bit". I don't know after which software installation did this error occur, but the only application affected by this is cheat engine 6.6, and unable to start this application. I tried some fixes like installing newer version of .net framework, directx and microsoft visual libraries. But nothing seems to work.

And BTW I'm using windows 10 Enterprise edition 64 bit. And this application was working normally before. But not now.

EDIT: According to Dependency Walker suggested by @magicandre, first of all dependency walker x64 bit version did not work on my x64 bit windows, so I used the x86 version.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzgcv08b7F8kcHN2OHZBNmJWODA) is the link to view the log file. I have included the log window pictures and the *.dwi file.

Answer (score 5):

The error `0xc000007b` means `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. This means an application tries to load DLLs with the wrong CPU architecture. So a 32Bit application tries to load 64Bit Dlls or the opposite (64Bit app tries to load 32Bit DLLs).

Most of the times it happens when users get messages about missing DLLs and download DLLs from 3rd party sites and copy them to system32 folder. Remove the effected software and reinstall the tool with all its dependencies from scratch.

Comment: Should I restart my PC afterwards?

Comment: if you get a message that you need to restart to finish setup, yes do it.

Comment: it didn't work. Even after a restart. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: use depends.exe to trace which DLL : http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx is causing it

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly edited your answer. Instead of my question.

Comment: I have no idea why you get this. Ask developers: https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine/issues

Comment: I have submitted this error on github. Will revert as soon as I get any response from them.

Comment: I am able to use the x86 version of the cheat engine, it's only the x64 version. Also in dependency walker the x86 version of cheat engine gives the same errors. So I think it's not about these errors, that is preventing the x64 version of CE. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

0xc00007b also currently can be provoked by Windows Defender Address space layout randomization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795377/10141885